# ADO & DAO Introduction

Tags: vba, vb6, ado, dao

I am looking for some material giving introduction to DAO and ADO  usage in VBA. Most of the material i came across give examples of how to use them. I am looking for a broader theory based definition of what they are and how they came about and the requirements for their usage.

thanks
regards
tksy

Answer (score -1, accepted):

See [Data Access Using Data Access Objects (DAO)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa266542(VS.60).aspx) and [Microsoft ActiveX Data Objects (ADO)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms675532(VS.85).aspx)

Answer (score 0):

If you are considering both ADO and DAO then it's likely you are interested in MS Access or Jet as a data source, in which case the following KB article is useful:

[Choosing ADO or DAO for Working with Access Databases](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa164825(office.10).aspx)